# How can I make a automatic resize text that recognizes my window size

Tags: html, css

I was doing a website, and I have a problem.
When the page is full screen, it looks like this:

[image]

But then when I resize the window, it looks like this:

[image]

```
.about p {
padding: 0px 500px;
font-size: 100%;
}
```

This is the css of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.about p{
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

This should work. Make sure this is correct too:

```
 *{
box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

The problem is that your code isn't responsive enough - that's all.